# Disable SIGSTOP stop on forked processes when tracing with `PTRACE_TRACEME`

Tags: linux, ptrace

According to the `ptrace` documentation.

> Stop the tracee at the next `clone(2)` and automatically start tracing the newly cloned process, which will start with a `SIGSTOP`, or `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` if `PTRACE_SEIZE` was used.

The problem is that `SIGSTOP` may not be caused by `ptrace` at all - even the user can send this signal to the process. Child process being stopped by `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` would be more than perfect in this case.

I'm spawning a child process myself so using `PTRACE_TRACEME` is the best way to start tracing it - it's free of race conditions. If I insist on using `PTRACE_SEIZE` instead, the child process may have already exited before I call `PTRACE_SEIZE` in the parent process.

Is there any way to prevent the child process from receiving a plain `SIGSTOP` when tracing with `PTRACE_TRACEME`?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you can't.

There is good news, however. Since Linux version 3.4, `ptrace` supports a new operation, `PTRACE_SEIZE`. It is from the parent rather than the child, so the attach semantics are somewhat different. Other than that, it has a few differences, one of which is that it solves this particular problem.

You will need to read the man page to get the gory details. Pretty much everything about the way events are reported has changed if you use it. This problem (along with similar ones) is precisely the reason it was introduced, so if that problem bothers you, you should definitely use `PTRACE_SEIZE` instead of `PTRACE_TRACEME`, despite the inconvenience.